# How can I show a custom annotation only once on a faceted ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

[image: Please see this]

I have made a faceted graph in `ggplot2` (see above picture) that I would like to add an additional legend to indicate the alphabetical index that I have used on the X and Y axes of the plot in addition to the color legend shown.

I was able to make this using `annotation_custom`, but the annotation appeared 6 times, once on each facet. I want to place it just once below the color bar index. See image below.[image: Multiple times the legend appears.]

My code for ggplot2 is given as below

```
library(ggplot2)
corrma <- ggplot(samelt, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "steelblue", high = "tomato2", 
                       mid = "white",  
                       midpoint = 0,
                       limit = c(-1,1)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = s3) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = s3) +
  coord_fixed() +
  facet_wrap( ~ Country, nrow = 2) +
  labs(title = "Correlation Matrix of South Asian Indicators") +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal")+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm")) 

text <- paste(  "a - Age_dpdn_ratio_wkpop\n",
                "b - Birth_rt\n",
                "c - Death_rt\n",
                "d - Fertility_rt\n",
                "e - Health_exp_pcofGDP\n",
                "f - Life_exp\n",
                "g - Private_hlth_exp_pc_oftotal\n",
                "h - ruralpop_drnkwater_pc", sep = " ")

text.p <- ggparagraph(text = text, face = "italic", size = 8, color = "black")

corrma + annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(text.p))
```

After several trials, I found that `cowplot` gives the nearest possible solution. A figure of it given below. [image: THIS]. The codeline added is like this. Also, to mention here that margins of plot have been trimmed too.

```
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(corma, text.p, nrow = 2, ncol=1, align= "v", axis = "l", rel_widths = c(1, .1), rel_heights = c(1, .1))
```

This I guess can only be the temporary workaround.

```
structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 
8L), .Label = c("ruralpop_drnkwater_pc", "Life_exp", "Fertility_rt", 
"Private_hlth_exp_pc_oftotal", "Death_rt", "Health_exp_pcofGDP", 
"Birth_rt", "Age_dpdn_ratio_wkpop"), class = "factor"), Var2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("ruralpop_drnkwater_pc", 
"Life_exp", "Fertility_rt", "Private_hlth_exp_pc_oftotal", "Death_rt", 
"Health_exp_pcofGDP", "Birth_rt", "Age_dpdn_ratio_wkpop"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(1, 1, -1, -0.79, -1, -0.98, -1, -1, 1, -1, -0.79, 
    -1, -0.98, -1, -1, 1, 0.8, 1, 0.98, 1, 1, 1, 0.76, 0.77, 
    0.82, 0.78, 1, 0.98, 1, 1, 1, 0.97, 0.98, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    -0.98, 0.63, -1, -0.48, -0.82, -0.99, 1, -0.97, 0.59, -0.99, 
    -0.53, -0.8, -0.98, 1, -0.7, 0.99, 0.38, 0.92, 0.99, 1, -0.64, 
    0.21, -0.72, -0.73, 1, 0.47, 0.87, 0.99, 1, 0.17, 0.36, 1, 
    0.89, 1, 1, 1, -0.99, 0.87, -0.99, 0.56, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0.88, 
    -1, 0.56, -1, -1, 1, -0.89, 1, -0.55, 1, 1, 1, -0.89, 0.37, 
    -0.88, -0.88, 1, -0.56, 1, 1, 1, -0.55, -0.58, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, -1, 0.58, -0.98, 0.64, -1, -0.98, 1, -1, 0.54, -1, 0.62, 
    -1, -0.95, 1, -0.57, 0.99, -0.63, 1, 0.97, 1, -0.48, 0.41, 
    -0.58, -0.68, 1, -0.6, 0.99, 0.92, 1, -0.64, -0.67, 1, 0.97, 
    1, 1, 0.99, -0.99, 0.74, -0.97, -0.89, -0.99, -0.99, 1, -1, 
    0.79, -0.99, -0.91, -1, -1, 1, -0.8, 0.99, 0.91, 1, 1, 1, 
    -0.84, -0.77, -0.8, -0.82, 1, 0.92, 0.99, 1, 1, 0.91, 0.91, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0.93, -0.52, 0.89, -0.47, -0.9, -0.78, 0.02, 
    1, -0.18, 0.69, -0.77, -0.76, -0.5, -0.34, 1, -0.71, -0.44, 
    0.7, 0.94, -0.79, 1, -0.1, -0.82, -0.89, 0.29, 1, 0.25, -0.14, 
    0.84, 1, 0.87, -0.24, 1, -0.59, 1), Country = c("India", 
    "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", 
    "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", 
    "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", 
    "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", 
    "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", 
    "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", 
    "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", 
    "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", 
    "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", 
    "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", 
    "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", 
    "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", 
    "Pakistan", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", 
    "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", 
    "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", 
    "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", 
    "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", 
    "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", 
    "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", 
    "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", 
    "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", 
    "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", 
    "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", 
    "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", 
    "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", 
    "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", 
    "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", 
    "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", 
    "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", 
    "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", 
    "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", 
    "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", 
    "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", 
    "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", 
    "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", 
    "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", 
    "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", 
    "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka")), .Names = c("Var1", 
"Var2", "value", "Country"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", 
"37", "38", "39", "40", "46", "47", "48", "55", "56", "64", "17", 
"25", "33", "41", "51", "61", "71", "81", "101", "111", "121", 
"131", "141", "151", "161", "191", "201", "211", "221", "231", 
"241", "281", "291", "301", "311", "321", "371", "381", "391", 
"401", "461", "471", "481", "551", "561", "641", "18", "26", 
"34", "42", "52", "62", "72", "82", "102", "112", "122", "132", 
"142", "152", "162", "192", "202", "212", "222", "232", "242", 
"282", "292", "302", "312", "322", "372", "382", "392", "402", 
"462", "472", "482", "552", "562", "642", "110", "27", "35", 
"43", "53", "63", "73", "83", "103", "113", "123", "133", "143", 
"153", "163", "193", "203", "213", "223", "233", "243", "283", 
"293", "303", "313", "323", "373", "383", "393", "403", "463", 
"473", "483", "553", "563", "643", "114", "210", "36", "44", 
"54", "65", "74", "84", "104", "115", "124", "134", "144", "154", 
"164", "194", "204", "214", "224", "234", "244", "284", "294", 
"304", "314", "324", "374", "384", "394", "404", "464", "474", 
"484", "554", "564", "644", "116", "215", "310", "45", "57", 
"66", "75", "85", "105", "117", "125", "135", "145", "155", "165", 
"195", "205", "216", "225", "235", "245", "285", "295", "305", 
"315", "325", "375", "385", "395", "405", "465", "475", "485", 
"555", "565", "645"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: All I need is an annotation method for the entire plot as one single time not the 6 times as it shows.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `egg::geom_custom()`

```
d <- data.frame(vs = 1, x=30, y=300)
d$grob <- list(grid::textGrob('test'))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,disp)) + facet_wrap(~vs) + geom_point() +
  egg::geom_custom(data = d, aes(x,y,data=grob), grob_fun = identity,
                   inherit.aes = F)
```

Comment: Error: Object egg not found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether there is a way to achieve what you want using an automatically generated legend. A brief description of the problem: for this to work there must be a mapping from some `geom_*` to values in the data which is not the case your example.

Perhaps there is a more elegant way to do this but here is an example which uses `ggplotGrob()` and `annotation_custom()` together with `grid::grid.draw()`:

The idea here is to place a foreign graphical element, called a *grob* (in this case an annotation), in the ggplot2. I use the numeric columns in the `mpg` data set in the example below since you didn't provide any data. Note that I've slightly modified your code (justification of the color gradient legend):

```
# long format of the numeric columns in `mpg`
d <- cor(mpg %> % select_if(is.numeric)) %> % reshape2::melt()

# axis labels
s3 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

# legend keys
labs <- c("a - engine displacement\nb - year of manufacture\nc - number of cylinders\nd - city miles per gallon\ne - highway miles per gallon")

p <- ggplot(data = d) +
     geom_tile(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value), color = "white") +
     scale_fill_gradient2(low = "steelblue", high = "tomato2",
        mid = "white",
        midpoint = 0,
        limit = c(-1, 1)) +
     theme_minimal() +
     scale_y_discrete(labels = s3) +
     scale_x_discrete(labels = s3) +
     theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.justification = "top") +
     labs(fill = "Pearson\nCoefficient")
```

Add the annotation by appending

```
+ annotation_custom(textGrob(label = labs, just = "left",
                           gp = gpar(fontsize = 11)), 
                  ymin = 1, ymax = 4, xmin = 6.5)
```

to the above. Next, generate a ggplot2 grob, turn off clipping and draw the result.

```
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
g$layout$clip[g$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"
grid::grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: a fundamental problem with above solution is that this text repeats number of times with each facet plot. If 6 plots are faceted. This text a,b,c... also repeats 6 times on each plot.